# How much red wine is too much?

Tags: alcohol

I usually drink about half a glass of red wine every day at dinner. Over a period of 4 or 5 days, I'll usually consume a 750 mL bottle of red wine.

Is about 150 mL of red wine every day a good amount for your health, or it is too much?

Comment: Good for you mental or physical health? Physically, the good properties of red wine can be consumed from grapes, they don't need to be fermented

Comment: @TFD That last sentence is interesting but demands a cite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is moderate alcohol consumption beneficial for maximizing life expectancy?](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/585/is-moderate-alcohol-consumption-beneficial-for-maximizing-life-expectancy)